# how to extract one element from a site

Tags: python, scrapy

i want to extract contact information from the site:
http://www.smtnet.com/company/index.cfm?fuseaction=view_company&company_id=49509
i already done by the code as below:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get( "http://www.smtnet.com/company/index.cfm?fuseaction=view_company&company_id=49509")
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
Company_Name = sel.xpath('*//p[1]/strong/text()').extract_first()
Country=sel.xpath('*//p[2]/text()').extract()[-2]
webSite = ????
```

but i failed to exact the company website,it should be https://www.europlacer.com/.

ay one can tell me how to extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the `href` attribute of "Visit Website" button, then use this:

```
Company_URL = sel.xpath("//div[@id = 'tabs-1']/p[3]/a/@href").extract_first()
```

But, the above code will return you only this:

```
act_open_company_page.cfm?url_id=70098
```

Since the URL of the company (i.e. 'https://www.europlacer.com/') is NOT directly stored in the `href` attribute. (It is resolved later using a javascript) But if you closely look at the source:

```
<a onclick="return trackOutboundLink('company_url','http://www.europlacer.com','49509');" href="act_open_company_page.cfm?url_id=70098" target="_blank" class=""><img src="/images/buttons/visit-website.jpg" alt="Visit EUROPLACER website" class=""></a>
```

You can see the direct URL is present as an argument to the function in `onclick`attribute so you need to extract it out from there. First, to extract the `onclick` attribute's value, do this:

```
URL = sel.xpath("//div[@id = 'tabs-1']/p[3]/a/@onclick").extract_first()
```

Then, extract your required URL from it like this:

```
URL = URL.split(",")[1]
URL = URL.strip("\'")  // to remove the leading and trailing quotes
```

Another method to extract the URL would be to actually resolve the value of the `href` attribute. You can see, when you click on the link, it becomes something like:

```
http://www.smtnet.com/company/act_open_company_page.cfm?url_id=70098
```

So, the trick would be to prepend the hostname ("http://www.smtnet.com"), load the URL and then extract the loaded URL once it changes. But the first method I described in my answer would be lot easier.

Additionally for the company name, I think you should try this:

```
Company_Name = sel.xpath('//header/h1/text()').extract_first()
```

Since, the above line prints only the company name (i.e. "EUROPLACER"). Your code takes in some text as well.

Comment: You are welcome. If you found the answer useful, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you inspect the *Visit website* button in the developer console, you see this

```
<a onclick="return trackOutboundLink('company_url','http://www.europlacer.com','49509');" href="act_open_company_page.cfm?url_id=70098" target="_blank">
    <img src="/images/buttons/visit-website.jpg" alt="Visit EUROPLACER website">
  </a>
```

You want to grab the Anchor element and retrieve the URL from the onclick attribute like so

```
company_link_handler = sel.xpath('//*[@id="tabs-1"]/p[3]/a').attrib.get('onclick')
website = company_link_handler.split(',')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Find a unique element: you can't use CSS class or element's id to get the element, so you have to find a unique element that helps you to get the targeted element. This `img` can help you:

[image]

So, you can get it like this:

```
sel.xpath('//img[@src="/images/buttons/visit-website.jpg"]')
```

**Second**

Get targeted element: how can this unique element help you? The element with the company URL is its parent node (we can reach it with `/..`) and we need its `onclick`:

```
sel.xpath('//img[@src="/images/buttons/visit-website.jpg"]/../@onclick')
```

**Final step**

Extract demanded text: you can use many methods and tools, I just test regex and it works properly:

```
s=sel.xpath('//img[@src="/images/buttons/visit-website.jpg"]/../@onclick').extract_first()
x=re.search("(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s']{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s']{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s']{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s']{2,})",s)
result=x.group(0)
```

Note that I make little changes and use the regex pattern mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3809435/1578952). Don't forget to import `re` package also.

Comment: thanks, but i check regex, but it don't work for me, it returns expected string or buffer

Comment: It was my fault, `extract_first()` was missed. I updated the code.